# Where does maven call make?

Tags: linux, maven

I am a newbie working with maven.
I have compiled an application using a maven plug-in for compile goal.
When I execute: `mvn compile` I see this.

```
[user@pc111 userAPP]$ mvn compile
make -C ./configure install
make[1]:Entering directory `directory path'
perl /filepath/file.pl O.linux-x86_64 ../..
mkdir O.Common
make -C O.linux-x86_64 -f ../Makefile TOP=../.. T_A=linux-x86_64 install
make[2]: Entering directory `directory path´
perl /filepath2/file2.pl
...
```

And my question is:

**Where does maven call make?**

Because having a look at the mvn binary it calls java and the compiled mojo creates an object that extends to AbstractMojo. But where is make called? My project has many makefiles.
As I said I am newbie so if some info is confusing or other info is needed please just tell me.
Thanks for your help. 
And sorry for my English but it is not my native language.

Edit: This is my pom.xml.

```
<!--

 Project       : My Project

 Description   : Project description file for App

 Authors       : This file was generated by 


-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
<packaging>java</packaging>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<name>TEST module</name>
<description>TEST module</description>


<!-- project properties -->
<properties>
    <unit.type>module</unit.type>
</properties>

<!-- parent pom.xml -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-mycompany-settings</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</parent>

<!-- unit owner and developers -->
<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>developer</id>
        <roles>
            <role>unit owner</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
</developers>

<!-- configuration of how the project is built -->
<build>
    <!-- default phase is compile -->
    <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
    <!-- this command is executed if you just write 'mvn' -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mycompany-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <packaging>
                    <!--"some packaging config"-->
                </packaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

looking in pom.xml the mojo responsible of executing make should be the compileMojo. But where can I find the code where make is called. Because in ../mojos/build/CompileMojo.java nothing calls make. could executeMojo() method be the responsible to call make?

Comment: You should post your pom.xml here and then we can help you.

Comment: how i undestand maven works, is maven executes mojos on different phases of lifecycle, and make is executed not by maven directly but by one of mojos. if you post content of your pom file, we can easly pointed out which one is responsible for executing make

Comment: looking in pom.xml the mojo responsible of executing make should be the compileMojo. But where can I find the code where make is called. Because in ../mojos/build/CompileMojo.java nothing calls make. could executeMojo() method be the responsible to call make?

Comment: what this `maven-mycompany-plugin` plugin doing? are you sure tyou executing this pom, not ie parent pom?

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a framework to orchestrate many different plugins to build something.

In your case, one of the plugins is calling `make`.

Since Maven logs which plugins it runs, all you need to do is enable the log output again. For some reason, your invocation of `mvn` doesn't print anything. You need to figure out why that is. Look for the command line option `-q` in `$MVN_OPTS` or `~/.mavenrc`.